# Drupal Set term programmatically for a node

Tags: drupal, drupal-6, drupal-taxonomy

I want to update some nodes in my system and update a particular taxonomy attach to them. I need to do this work programmatically. I have node ids and term id and want to attach this term to this particular node. What should do the trick here??

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To get the node:

```
$node = node_load($X); // $X is node ID.
```

To attache a term ID - note that this is very different in D7:

```
$node->taxonomy[$tid] = taxonomy_get_term($tid); // $tid is attaching term ID.
```

To add revision:

```
$node->revision = 1; 
$node->log = "Programatically attached taxonomy term.";
```

To save the node - if the node is new:

```
node_submit($node);
node_save($node);
```

or, to save the node if it's an existing node:

```
node_save($node);
```

---

In Drupal 7, terms are attached as normal field items so field_first_name[0] means the first occurrence of the field. Don't confuse that functionality with terms. You can add as many as terms you want.

Update: Thanks to [kliker](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3963647/kliker) for the [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/5590924), which was unfortunately rejected. It [seems](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/251338/784877) I have to edit the post myself to get his changed into this answer.